# Can't start Genymotion Emulator from Android Studio Plugin

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I've seen many posts with a similar problem and tried many solutions but so far none have helped.  This all started after I upgraded Genymotion from 2.5.2 to 2.6.0.

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.  The Genymotion plugin is version 1.0.7.  VirtualBox is 5.0.12 r104815

When I try to start a Genymotion Emulator I get:

[image]

I have several machines defined and all do this.

However, I can start them from the Genymotion app.

One other piece of information...if I have Android Studio and Genymotion running I get the following error when I try to issue any adb command from the command line:

adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:

I've tried restarting the computer, restarting Android Studio, and removing and reloading the plugin.  I've also set Genymotion to use the same adb that Android Studio uses.

Any ideas?  Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

This is actually 2 separate problems and I've found the solution for one and a workaround for the other.

Can't start Genymotion Emulator from Android Studio Plugin - I resolved this for now by reverting to Genymotion 2.5.2.  I'll still need to figure out why 2.6.0 causes a problem but for now I can start emulator machines from the Android Studio plugin.

adb server is out of date - This is caused by more than one instance of adb on the machine.  In my case, Android Studio was using the one in ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools, but when I tried issuing adb commands in terminal it was using the one in /usr/bin.  I'll either try creating a symbolic link in /usr/bin to point to ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools, or I'll add ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools to my Path environment variable.

Rich